# Remove + character from field which has been filled via url

Tags: javascript, url, field, character

I have a form which is filled in via a url, currently I use the  code:

```
    var keyword1 = keyword1before.replace(/\s+/g,'+');
```

to remove the + symbol so the user does not need to add this to the form. However when the url is submitted back into the site the + symbol appears between words. How can I remove this so when the url is submitted multiple words appear without + between them in each field?

Comment: By filled in by a url do you mean fields are auto filled in by something like a query string? If so you should probably use HttpUtility.UrlDecode when reading them. The reason the `+` signs replaced spaces is that the query string params were probably url encoded. Are you definitely submitting the field back or is it possible that you are submitting whatever was read from the url? Try changing what is put in the auto populated field and see if that gets submitted.

Comment: yeah I have a string which is the final url. everything submitted is returned, it is just keyowrds with mutliple words have a + rather than a space